# How to catch execution error in XMLService getAttribute method?

Tags: google-apps-script, xml-parsing

I'm using this script in a Google Sheets spreadsheet to parse a table in a web page and to store results:

```
    var doc = XmlService.parse(result);
    var html = doc.getRootElement();
    var resulttable = getElementsByClassName(html, 'resulttable')[0];

    var descendants = html.getDescendants();
    descendants.push(html);  
    for(var i in descendants) {
      var elt = descendants[i].asElement();  <== it crashes
      if(elt != null) {
        var test = elt.getAttributes();
        var test_bis = elt.getAttribute('http-equiv');   <== it does not crashes: 'http-equiv' exists
        var classes = elt.getAttribute('class');   <== it crashes:'class' does not exists
      }
    }
```

As it's shown, I have some errors (simply raised as "server errors") in the marked lines of this code. I also put `try...catch` block, but they don't catch the errors: the script terminates abruptly.

How can I catch the errors so as to let the script continuing despite some of these XML errors?

My expectations were to have undefined elements when the `asElement` or the `getAttribute` methods fail.

---

To parse the URL I was using [this approach](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/learn-by-example/parsing-html)

```
  var url = "https://albopretorio.comune.gravina.ba.it/fo/?ente=GravinaInPuglia";
  var today = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "dd/MM/yyyy");

  var payload =
      {
        "tipoSubmit":"ricerca",
        "enti":"GravinaInPuglia",
        "uo":"",
        "tipoatto":"",
        "anno":"",
        "numda":"",
        "numa":"",
        "annoatto":"",
        "numatto":"",
        "datada":"",
        "dataa":"",
        "pubblicatoda":today,
        "pubblicatoa":"",
        "presenteal":"",
        "chiave":"",
        "provenienza":"",
      };
  
  var options =
      {
        "method"  : "POST",
        "payload" : payload,   
        "followRedirects" : true,
        "muteHttpExceptions": true
      };
var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
```

Comment: `elt.getAttribute('class');` [should return null](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/element#getattributename) if the attribute does not exist, not crash the execution. If the `ContentType` is not `ELEMENT`, `descendants[i].asElement();` [should also return null](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/content#asElement()). Can you share the code related to `result` and `element`, so that this behaviour can be reproduced?

Comment: @Iamblichus I edited the question to insert the request from where I get the page to parse

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. The script is running successfully till the end, no errors.

Comment: How are you executing this? Is this a web app, as in the example you referenced?

Comment: yes. In a script into a google spreadsheet to fill the sheet

Comment: Could you share a sanitized copy of the spreadsheet you are working on? I'm unable to reproduce this behaviour.

Comment: I could share with you the spreadsheet but I need your email at least. Or I can post here the whole function but there is no more than I wrote on the question.

Comment: You can make a sanitized copy (remove all sensitive information) and make this copy public.

Comment: I'm traying to do this.
Anyway I've checked that when I loop on descendants elements, the 1st element in the array is a TEXT element and if I do `descendants[i].asText();` it works while `descendants[i].asElement();` crashes (i.e. exit abruptly by the script execution: no excepritions raised)

Comment: @Iamblichus here is the link to the file https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1g3o1peSILOILFiQovPSjOAwtFa4LZjiacmYAPscadI4/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

You don't know which [ContentType](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/content-type) each `descendant` is, so you don't know which method you should use to cast the node.

#### Solution:

For each `descendant`, check for the corresponding `ContentType` with the method [getType()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/content#getType()). You can use the returned value (the `ContentType`) and a [switch statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) to use one method or another.

#### Code snippet:

```js
for (var i in descendants) {
  var contentType = descendants[i].getType();
  var elt;
  switch (contentType.toString()) {
    case 'TEXT':
      elt = descendants[i].asText();
      break;
    case 'ELEMENT':
      elt = descedants[i].asElement();
      break;
    // Add other possible ContentTypes, if necessary
```

#### Update: Issue with getAttribute:

In order to avoid the script trying retrieve an attribute that does not exist, you can retrieve an array of the attribute names for this element, and then check if your attribute is included in that array:

```js
var attributes = elt.getAttributes().map(attribute => attribute.getName());
if (attributes.includes('class')) {
  var classes = elt.getAttribute('class');
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Enum ContentType](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/content-type)
- [Interface Content: getType()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/content#getType())
- [switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)

Comment: I need to switch on contentType.toString().
But anyway it remains the problem on the `getAttribute()` that crashes instead of returning `null` if the atribute is not present

Comment: @Manticore I updated my answer, please let me know if that works for you.

Comment: It works like a charm!! Thank you very much !! Anyway the getAttribute() should return null, according the reference.

Comment: @Manticore You're welcome. Yes, getAttribute() should return null, as I said before, and actually I could not reproduce the behaviour you were getting when executing your script (no error appeared). But if you are still experiencing this and you have a way to reproduce this, you could file a bug in Issue Tracker. Also, remember that you can accept answers that you consider helpful. This is useful because this community relies on it to share knowledge to other users.